# Split text file Into multiple files when it hits a certain string

Tags: regex, vbscript

I'm fairly new to programming and I got tasked this at work. I need to split the text file every time it hits the string characters `{1:` and ends with `-}` and then create a new text file. See example below:

Original Text file:

```
{1:F01BOF}{2:I940B}{4:dfdfd
:20:06AUG
:25:64
-}{1:F01BO}{2:I940{4:dfdfd
:20:06AUG2
:25:6412
:64:C200806EUR1748473,62
-}{1:F01}{2:I940XN}{4:fvfddf
:20:06AUG81-}
```

New Text1:

```
{1:F01BOF}{2:I940B}{4:dfdfd
:20:06AUG
:25:64
-}
```

New Text2

```
{1:F01BO}{2:I940{4:dfdfd
:20:06AUG2
:25:6412
:64:C200806EUR1748473,62
-}
```

New Text3:

```
{1:F01}{2:I940XN}{4:fvfddf
:20:06AUG81-}
```

I was using the code below but it doesn't seem to pick up the curly bracket character

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

data = split(fso.OpenTextFile("C:\JustNeeded.txt").ReadAll, "{1")

For i = 1 To UBound(data)
  fso.OpenTextFile("new" & i & ".txt", 2, True).Write "{1" & data(i)
Next
```

I was reading up on regex, should I be using that instead? Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: This seems like some JSON. What is the format of that text file? I'm sure there are parsers

Comment: Hi Cid, yes it could be the way its sent to company but when I get it, its in a .txt file in the format above.

Comment: When you open the input text file in Notepad, and click "Save As..." - what encoding does Notepad show?

Comment: Hi Tomalak, When I put it into notepad++ and save as it shows Save as type "All Types(*.*)"

Comment: No, I'm not asking for the type. I'm asking for the file encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Arrays in VBScript are 0-based. It's better to start your loop from 0.
- It's smarter to split at the end delimiter `-}`, so the first element of the split result is not empty.
- I'm using `With` blocks to organize the code. "Doing it all on one line" becomes hard to read quickly.
- I'm using `Option Explicit` so all variables must be properly declared. This prevents hard-to-debug issues with typos in variable names, using `Option Explicit` with all your VB code a really good habit to get into.
- Creating constants with a speaking name (such as `ForWriting`) is much nicer than using opaque "magic numbers" like `2`.
- Note you're writing the file as Unicode, but you're not reading it as Unicode. This may or may not be intentional, it's your call.
- calling `.Close` on a file handle is not strictly necessary here, but it's good manners.

Improved code:

```
Option Explicit

Dim FSO, text, parts, i

Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

With FSO.OpenTextFile("C:\JustNeeded.txt", ForReading)
    text = .ReadAll
    .Close
End with

parts = Split(text, "-}")

For i = 0 To UBound(parts) - 1
    If Len(parts(i)) > 0 Then
        With FSO.OpenTextFile("new" & (i + 1) & ".txt", ForWriting, True)
            .Write parts(i) & "-}"
            .Close
        End With
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Hi Tomalak, Thanks for the help. Ok I tried the code above and it seem to run without error but there is no new files appearing. I'm running the code using a .bat file is this ok?

Comment: @jemac How you start the code is not important, a BAT file is as good as any other method. If the code runs without errors that's half the way. I'm sure it writes output files (it does, I tested it), it just does not writ them *next to the input file*. Search for the files.

Comment: hey Tomalak, got it working, had the file name messed up. thanks for all the help and tips above.